# Cytoscape.js: hide cxtmenu entries depending on node?

Tags: contextmenu, cytoscape.js

I use `cytoscape-cxtmenu.js` to provide commands on nodes but not all nodes support all commands. **How can I only show the commands that a node supports?**

```
var defaults = {
    selector: 'node',
    commands: [
        // everyone has a name
        {content: 'tell name',
         select: function(node) {console.log(node.data().name);}},
        // not everyone has a spouse
        {content: 'tell spouse',
         select: function(node) {console.log(node.data().spouse);}},
]};

var cxtmenuApi = cy.cxtmenu(defaults);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use multiple context menus, each with a different selector.

```
var cxtmenuApi1 = cy.cxtmenu({ selector: 'node[foo="bar"]' /* ... */ });

var cxtmenuApi2 = cy.cxtmenu({ selector: 'node[foo="baz"]' /* ... */ });
```

Each menu has its own set of commands, so you can just use the same commands but with some commands disabled (`disabled: true`) in 1 but enabled in 2, etc.

Alternatively, you could specify only the commands that apply to each set of nodes -- but then the relative positions of commands could be different from node to node.